# How to reference Standard library from Full .Net when it have it's own NuGet dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core, .net-standard

I have some back-end logic in **.NET Standard library** (let's call it `Service`) and have to have two types of entry point: **.Net Core Console App** and a **Windows Service** as entry points to that logic. My `Service` library have it's own dependencies and one of those dependencies (`DAL`) makes use of NuGet, specifically MongoDB.Driver. When I compile it, in `bin/debug` Service don't have any mongo related libraries. But `Net Core Console App` do have `deps.json`, `runtimeconfig.json`, `runtimeconfig.dev.json` files and as far as I understand this is why everything runs perfectly with Core Console.

But it don't work with Windows Service (Net 4.6.1) that referencing `Standard`. There is also no Mongo in `bin/Debug` and as a result when I run it (it is configured as a console application too) I get

`FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MongoDB.Driver, Version=2.5.0.0`

and this is reasonable message... but how this supposed to work then? Usually NuGet dependencies in Full .Net are copied with the target project (and also copied to those who references this project). This is not the case with Standard Libraries. I just afraid to reinvent the wheel here, may be there are good existing solution?

Comment: Does your windows server project use the latest csproj format (2017)?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue; add the following to the .csproj of your full .NET project.
It is explained on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/481)

```
<PropertyGroup>  
   <RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
   <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
   <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, it explains a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this works too but should be done in csproj of .Net Standard.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I'm not sure which approach is better, waiting for comments.

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like the Full.Net project just falls back to Packages.config because this is set by default in VS Setting. I've switched this to PackageReference and removead all changes in proj files - it now works just as is.

[image]